# Which API can I use to format an int to 2 digits?

Tags: java, formatting, int

What API can I use to format an `int` to be 2 digits long?

For example, in this loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
   System.out.println("i is " + i);
}
```

What can I use to make sure `i` is printed out like `01`, `02`, `10`, `55` etc (assuming a range of 01-99 )

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could simply do

```
System.out.printf("i is %02d%n", i);
```

Have a look at the documentation for [`Formatter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) for details. Relevant parts are:

> - The format specifiers for general, character, and numeric types have the following syntax:
>         `%[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion`

(In this particular case, you have `0` as flag, `2` as width, and `d` as conversion.)

> **Conversion**
>   `'d'`    integral      The result is formatted as a decimal integer
>
> **Flags**
>   `'0'`                     The result will be zero-padded

---

This formatting syntax can be used in a few other places as well, for instance like this:

```
String str = String.format("i is %02d", i);
```

Answer (score 10):

`String` class actually do formatting.

For your case, try:

`String.format("%02d",i)`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [DecimalFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) object.

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#00.###");
int test = 1;

System.out.println(formatter.format(test));
```

Will print "01".